# I could not create a queue in a storage account after I deployed my Azure batch

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues

I have an AzureBatch service that needs to write to a Storage Queue at the end of the Batch run. In my local machine when I run it, every thing seems to work OK, but when I deploy it to App Service, the queue is not being created. Also, I do not seem to get Blob to trigger after the batch Run.

As a back ground, I have two triggers (HTTP and Queue) in one function app running in Consumption price plan. Please help.

```
         StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new 
                   StorageCredentials(StorageAccountName, 
                   StorageAccountKey);
         CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new 
                    CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, useHttps: 
                    true);

        // Create a queue client for interacting with the queue service
        CloudQueueClient queueClient = 
                      storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

        CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference(queueName);

        try
        {
            await queue.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
```

I expect to see a queue created and msg added to it.Mind you, it works when I run it locally through the debugger.

Comment: So, no one is able to help?  :(

Comment: you mentioned that you have a queue trigger azure function, I suspect the queue trigger consume the queue message, so it does not exist in queue storage.

Comment: Ivan, thanks for replying to my queries. No, the Queue trigger did not consume it, because I can see from the Function App monitor, the trigger function have never been called. So, it is still a mystery.